# Retrieve records satisfying a condition and not satisfying another condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named `tuition`
I want to retrieve all the students who study `111` and who does not study `333`
This is what I can think of:

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f6411/3

```
stud_id | subject_id
--------------------
    1       111
    1       222
    2       222
    2       333
    3       111
    3       222
    3       333
    4       111
    4       222
```

**Output:**

```
stud_id
-------
   1
   4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three alternatives:

1. Using `HAVING` clause and `WHERE` clause:

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM tution 
   WHERE subject_id = 111 OR subject_id=333
   GROUP BY stud_id
   HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT subject_id)=1 AND subject_id<>333
   ```

   Result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/df178/1).
2. Using `HAVING` clause without `WHERE` clause:

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM tution 
   GROUP BY stud_id
   HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT subject_id)=2 AND subject_id =111 AND subject_id<>333
   ```

   Result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/86252/1).
3. Using `IN`:

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM tution
   WHERE subject_id=111
   AND stud_id NOT IN (SELECT stud_id FROM tution WHERE subject_id= 333)
   ```

   Result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f6411/8).

Result:

```
STUD_ID  SUBJECT_ID
1        111
4        111
```

Comment: 1. is incorrect. Your fiddle has `insert into tution values(2,111);` which wasn't part of OP's data. If you remove that row stud_id 2 will also be returned

Answer (score 1):

```
select stud_id from tution 
where stud_id not in (select stud_id from tution t 
                  where t.subject_id = 333) 
and subject_id = 111
```

[Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f6411/34)

Comment: Can you please explain your answer in very brief.

Comment: @MohitJain Fetch the `stud_id` which do not have the `subject_id=333`, so i get 1 and 4 in this case. Then adding one more filter with id's having `subject_id=111`, which results in 1,4 in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.stud_id FROM tuition t1 
WHERE t1.subject_id=111 
AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tuition t2 
               WHERE t1.stud_id=t2.stud_id 
               AND t2.subject_id = 333)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following show you all distinct student who satisfied given condition.

```
SELECT Distinct stud_id
FROM tution
WHERE subject_id=111
AND 
stud_id NOT IN (SELECT stud_id FROM tution WHERE subject_id= 333)
```